# asp.net html.listboxfor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How will I populate a ASP.NET MVC List box?
Make it non selectable?
how will i remove the selected items from the listbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC ModelBind ListBox With Multple Selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382747/mvc-modelbind-listbox-with-multple-selections)

Comment: Your second question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379125/make-drop-down-list-item-unselectable

Comment: If your list is non selectable how will you select the item to remove?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want an unselectable select?

```
 <%= Html.ListBoxFor( m => m.Choices, 
                      Model.ChoicesMenu,
                      new { disabled = "disabled" } ) %>
```

The idea is that your model needs to have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that will hold the possible key/value pairs for your selection, here the `ChoicesMenu`.  The actual values chosen, if it could be selected, would be posted in the `Choices` property.  Use the signature that allows you to specify html attributes and make it disabled prevent selecting it.  You can, of course, do this (or undo it) with javascript.

Model:

```
 public class ViewModel
 {
     public int[] Choices { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChoicesMenu { get; set; }
 }
```

Action (relevant bit)

```
 var model = new ViewModel
 {
     ChoicesMenu = db.Items
                     .Select( i => new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = i.Name,
                          Value = i.ID.ToString()
                      } );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[MVC ModelBind ListBox With Multple Selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382747/mvc-modelbind-listbox-with-multple-selections) Might give you the first answer.

You can disable the items in the listbox, but not the list box itself. If you set Visible to false, the whole listbox will not display.

Doing something like:

```
ListBox.Items[X].Selected = false
```

Will make the items non selectable.