# Html.ListBoxFor error problem asp.mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, listbox

I have something like this in my code and I am getting error:  Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name . What am I doing wrong ? Thanks for help

`@model IEnumerable<NHibernateFluentProject.Patient>`

`@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model, new SelectList(Model,"ID", "FirstName"));`

Comment: This is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826587/asp-net-html-listboxfor

Answer (score 6):

@Html.ListBoxFor is used for your strong typed viewmodel. which could help to bind to your property. First part will take a lambda expression for a single item as a default seleced for your listbox, second part will take the item collections to dispaly all the listbox items.
For example: you have following two classes.

```
public class HospitalViewModel
{
    public string SelectedPatient { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Patient> AllPatients { get; set; }
}
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

From you view, you should do something like

```
@model HospitalViewModel

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedPatient, new SelectList(Model.AllPatients,"Id", "FirstName"));
```

OR if you only want to bind all your patients to a listbox, then use Html.ListBox instead

```
@model IEnumerable<Patient>

@Html.ListBox("ListBoxName", new SelectList(Model,"Id", "FirstName"));
```

Comment: I'm looking for something like your answer, but instead of string SelectPatient is there a way to have a collection of multiple selections?  So if the user selects more than one patient they'll show up in some List of collection.  Any ideas?

Comment: @NullReference:  in your case, you may need a Ajax call to send a json object to include all your selected ListItems from the client side to the controller to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Allen.  I actually found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194143/challenges-with-selecting-values-in-listboxfor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a lambda expression containing the property to bind the listbox to.

Comment: @petro: `m => m.SomeProperty`