# How to do a @Html.DropDownListFor with this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I'm learning MVC3 and I want my drop down list to use `colors` as the data here. How can I do it?

I know that I can do it with `@Html.DropDownList("colors")` but I'm wondering how to do this with `@Html.DropDownListFor(....)`? I'm a bit stumped and any help plus explanation would be appreciated.

I'm putting it all in one page just for convenience, so this isn't real-world app here.

```
@functions {

    private class Colors
    {
        public int ColorsId { get; set; }
        public string ColorsName { get; set; }
    }

}

@{
    var list = new List<Colors>()
                {
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 1, ColorsName = "Red"},
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 2, ColorsName = "Blue"},
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 3, ColorsName = "White"}
                };
    var colors = new SelectList(list, "ColorsId", "ColorsName", 3);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor( ??? )
```

Comment: check my answer for this thread. It should be very similar.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097290/html-listboxfor-error-problem-asp-mvc-3/5176057#5176057

Comment: @AllenWang thanks. definitely a great answer too. upvoted that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => colors, colors)
```

Comment: can you help me understand the lambda expression here in `model => colors`?

Comment: The model is the expression that identifies the object containing the property to display and we return the collection of SelectListItems used to populate the drop down list

Comment: usually I see lambdas as x => x.something; this is interesting that it's not model => model.colors. Can you explain to me why by any chance? (c# beginner here)

Comment: If you would have used model.colors the compiler would have complained that this is a dynamic expression and it is not supported so I just returned colors and it worked. If you also look at the first paramter of this method is says Expression<Func<dynamic,SelectList>> so the returned value should not be a dynamic value

Comment: ahhh. thanks for that. I'm wondering though. I know lamda = "goes to" but here, where does "model" go to? i've never seen lambda being used without the left-side params not being used like that. mind if you could help me understand why it's possible to write a code like this? it looks like a 'hack' of some kind i think.. just to fulfill the Func<,>

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the type of model at the top of your page. Specify which property of the model is bound to the Drop Down using the lambda expression.

```
@model MyModel

@functions {

    private class Colors
    {
        public int ColorsId { get; set; }
        public string ColorsName { get; set; }
    }

}

@{
    var list = new List<Colors>()
                {
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 1, ColorsName = "Red"},
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 2, ColorsName = "Blue"},
                    new Colors() {ColorsId = 3, ColorsName = "White"}
                };
    var colors = new SelectList(list, "ColorsId", "ColorsName", 3);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.colors, colors)
```

Comment: can you help me understand the lambda expression here in `model => model.colors`?

Comment: It tells the `DropDownListFor` to bind to `colors` property of your model class.

Comment: how would you know that it looks at the Model property of the ViewPage? (I'm a c# beginner)

Comment: @JanCarloViray Because the `DropDownListFor` method can inspect the lambda expression you supply to build meta data needed to render the `<select>` tag. You can go through the MVC Source code to see exactly how its done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ColorsId, new SelectList(list, "ColorsId", "ColorsName")) %>
```

Comment: sorry didn't read it correctly.typo of colors instead of list